Model to generate 512x512 photos
how can I make this model generate 512x512 px images or bigger? Now it generates 64x64px images.I tried changing some values in the model but it didn't work. And how these convolutional layers work especially Conv2D and Conv2DTranspose? I don't understand how the image is resized in those layers.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cd /content/drive/MyDrive

dataset = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory = 'Humans', label_mode = None, image_size = (64,64), batch_size = 32,
    shuffle = True
).map(lambda x: x/255.0)

discriminator = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape = (64,64,3)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = 4, strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 4, strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 4, strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid')
    ]
)

latent_dim = 128
generator = keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Input(shape = (latent_dim,)),
        layers.Dense(8*8*128),
        layers.Reshape((8,8,128)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size = 4, strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size = 4, strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size = 4, strides = 2, padding = 'same'),
        layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size = 5,padding = 'same',activation = 'sigmoid')
    ]
)

opt_gen = keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
opt_disc = keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
loss_fn = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

for epoch in range(500):
  for idx, real in enumerate(tqdm(dataset)):
    batch_size = real.shape[0]
    random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape = (batch_size,latent_dim))
    fake = generator(random_latent_vectors)

    if idx % 50 == 0:
      img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(fake[0])
      img.save(f'gen_images/generated_img{epoch}_{idx}_.png')

    with tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      loss_disc_real = loss_fn(tf.ones((batch_size,1)), discriminator(real))
      loss_disc_fake = loss_fn(tf.zeros(batch_size,1), discriminator(fake))
      loss_disc = (loss_disc_real+loss_disc_fake)/2

    grads = disc_tape.gradient(loss_disc, discriminator.trainable_weights)

    opt_disc.apply_gradients(
        zip(grads, discriminator.trainable_weights)
    )

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape:
      fake = generator(random_latent_vectors)
      output = discriminator(fake)
      loss_gen = loss_fn(tf.ones(batch_size,1),output)

    grads = gen_tape.gradient(loss_gen, generator.trainable_weights)
    opt_gen.apply_gradients(
        zip(grads, generator.trainable_weights)
    )

I tried changing the image size and some values in the conv layers but it didn't work.

Your input images are 64x64.  You can certainly resize the output, but it's just going to stretch the pixels you have.  It can't generate new information where none exists.  What are you expecting this code to do?

In short, to make the generator generates images with larger dimension, you can add more Conv2DTranspose layer or increase the strides and/or kernel size.
Conv2D reduces the dimension of the input, e.g. the feature of shape (64, 64, 3) after being processed by Conv2D with 64 kernels, kernel_size=4, and strides=2 will become of shape (30, 30, 64). Here's a realted question regarding how to calculate the output size of a convolution.
Meanwhile, Conv2DTranspose does regular convolution but "reverses" the dimensional reduction so if you have an input of shape (30, 30, 64) and Conv2DTranpose with the same configuration as the Conv2D before, you would get an output of the original shape (64, 64, 3). I found this helpful article to learn about the concepts of convolution in machine learning.
Your generator starts with an input of shape (128,) and you expect it to have an output of shape (512, 512, 3). You can reverse your thought process and start backward. How do you arrange the Conv2D layers in a model so that it eventually outputs an array of size (128,). Then you can try reverse the process by changing the Conv2D layers into Conv2DTranspose and reverting the sequence.

The generator starts with layers.Dense(8*8*128), so 8 pixel × 8 pixel images. Each application of Conv2DTranspose with strides=2 and padding='same' doubles the size of the image. There are three layers, so the output is 8 pixels × 23 = 64 pixels by 64 pixels.
So if you add another layer, you will double again and get 128 × 128 pixels. Or, if you use a stride of 3 then each layer will inflate by a factor of 3. Or, if you changing the padding strategy, you can add pixels at the edges.
Remember that changes you make to the generated images may need corresponding changes to the discriminator.
To build some intuition, I suggest reading about convolution and "deconvolution" (really transposed convolution, not the same as deconvolution in signal processing) and playing a bit with different arguments. To get you started, here is an awesome tutorial (PDF) and here is one SO answer that might help; there may be others.
